# div as contenteditable: cursor is located below the div

Tags: css, contenteditable

I have a div that I defined it as contenteditable (behaves like an input).

I'm trying to write something so I click with the mouse within the div:

On chrome: everything is OK, the cursor is located in the div.

On Firefox: strange behavoir, the cursor is located below the div. **After you write something, it's fixed**.

I'm trying to make firefox to work as chrome.

This is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/730/

This is my div:

```
<div class="divAsInput" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.divAsInput {
    word-break: break-all;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
    box-shadow: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Please open it on Chrome and Firefox and click the mouse withing the div..

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like firefox has some issue with the padding cause there is nothing inside the `<div>`at start.. what about you try with `min-height` http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/731/

```
.divAsInput {
    min-height: 20px;
    word-break: break-all; 
    border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I will mark your answer about 5 minutes. Thank you!